# Are Chia seeds a 'super-food'?

Tags: nutrition

A recent [BBC article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-17476690) extolled the virtues of Chia seeds. My skeptical alarm bells were ringing throughout, as nearly every source quoted had a commercial interest in selling chia seeds. In particular, some pretty wild claims were made:

> Literally, you could live on this stuff because it's pretty much everything you need

> [...] chia reduces inflammation, improves heart health, and stabilises blood sugar levels. A few tablespoons are touted as remedying just about anything - without any ill effects

> "In terms of nutritional content, a tablespoon of chia is like a smoothie made from salmon, spinach and human growth hormone,"

> [chia is capable of] building muscle, lowering cholesterol, and reducing your risk of heart disease

To be precise:

- Is Chia capable of replacing a diet entirely (is it possible to live healthily on nothing but chia seeds)?
- Does chia have any recognised medicinal properties published in a medical journal?

Comment: @Chad My first question is clearly based on the claim in the last quote. My second question is based on the claims in the first and third quotes. I don't see what your problem is here.

Comment: I moved your primary claim to the top of the list to make it more visible.

Comment: I havent removed your second question.  Though I think the question would be better with out asking for that specifically since there is no claim that it is recognized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt anybody would test humans on a diet of any single product, especially one which is [30% fat by weight](http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3673), and which is [low in vitamins, iron and some other minerals](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3061/2).  That does not mean you could not survive for some time on enough of it (and water).

You can find many studies in the last 20 years of aspects of [Chia seeds via Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=chia%20seeds) or from similar sources.  A [systematic review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20028328) of Chia (*Salvia hispanica*) in 2009 said

> RESULTS:
>
> The available human and non-human studies show possible effectiveness
>   for allergies, angina, athletic performance enhancement, cancer,
>   coronary heart disease (CHD), heart attack, hormonal/endocrine
>   disorders, hyperlipidemia, hypertension, stroke, and vasodilatation.
>   Some evidence also suggests possible anticoagulant, antioxidant, and
>   antiviral effects of Salvia hispanica.
>
> CONCLUSION:
>
> There is limited evidence supporting the efficacy of Salvia hispanica
>   for any indication; thus far, only two clinical studies have examined
>   the effects of Salvia hispanica on cardiovascular disease (CVD) risk
>   factors (including body weight). One study showed some effects on some
>   CVD risk factors, while the other did not. Neither study showed any
>   effects of Salvia hispanica on weight loss. However, the historical
>   use of Salvia hispanica suggests that it is safe for consumption by
>   nonallergic individuals. Further rigorous examination is warranted
>   pertaining to the use of Salvia hispanica as a dietary supplement, as
>   well as in the treatment or prevention of human disease.